# Flutter Web: Loading data from URL fails

Tags: flutter, web, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

When trying to fetch image data inside a custom `ImageProvider` from an URL, I get an error:
`ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=https://<host>/api/v1/images/<imageId>/thumbnail-squared`

The host however has CORS enabled and returns a header `"access-control-allow-origin" -> "*"`.

The URL redirects a 302 to a signed google cloud storage file however. Might this be the issue?

Comment: Server side need to have SSL and URL have to start with https://
and need to open CORS policies

Comment: I use SSL and the `https` protocol prefix..

Comment: Is it in development mode?

Comment: Try creating a proxy server on your sub-domain. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74952201/8021111

Comment: Could you directly view the image on web browser?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution.

It is a server-side issue. Your server is not allowing or accepting your cross-origin request. But no worries, it's 10 mins' work.
All you need to do is configure your server. Doing that will allow or accept your request.

Steps:

#1. Open the Server's CPanel & then open CPanel File Manager.

#2. Look for the "public_html" directory.

#3. Look for the ".htaccess" file (Make sure you enable the view for hidden files.), Still, if you don't find the ".htaccess" file, create the ".htaccess" file.

#4. Paste the below-mentioned code in the ".htaccess" file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
```

#5. Save the ".htaccess" file.

Important:
If you have the SSL certificate, consider using the "https://" prefix. If you don't have the SSL certificate, consider using the "http://" prefix.

Reference link:
https://gist.github.com/nixta/0b98d7975562bc31c4c9